# Why is $\mathbb{Z}$ not a Kähler group?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is there some simple proof that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to the fundamental group of any compact Kähler manifold? This follows from the main result of https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.4350 which states that any $3$-manifold group which is Kähler must be finite. The simplest non-finite 3-manifold group is $\mathbb{Z} = \pi_{1}(S^{2} \times S^{1})$. So I was wondering, is there an argument to rule out this particularly simple group, without applying to a lot of machinery? (also historically when were we first able to rule this group out?)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If $X$ is a compact Kähler manifold, then $h^{p,q}(X) = h^{q,p}(X)$ and $b_k(X) = \sum_{p+q=k}h^{p,q}(X)$, so in particular, $b_1(X) = h^{1,0}(X) + h^{0,1}(X) = 2h^{1,0}(X)$ is even. Now,

$$b_1(X) = \operatorname{rank} H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}) = \operatorname{rank} \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X), \mathbb{Z}).$$

If $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}$, $b_1(X) = 1$ which is not even, so $X$ is not Kähler. More generally, if $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian, then it must have even rank.

Note, there are non-compact Kähler manifolds with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$, for example $X = \mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Also note, there are compact non-Kahler complex manifolds with $\pi_1 = \mathbb{Z}$, namely, the Hopf surface https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_surface

Answer (score 14):

Every free group is not Kähler (fundamental group of compact Kähler manifold).  In particular, a free group of rank 1 is not Kähler.

This follows since the rank of the abelianization of a Kähler group is even, even rank free groups contain finite index subgroups of odd rank (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780799/free-group-of-finite-rank-subgroup-of-finite-index) for example), and finite index subgroups correspond to covers of Kähler manifolds which are also Kähler.

This and other interesting examples can be found in [Fundamental Groups of Compact Kähler Manifold](http://www.ams.org/books/surv/044/surv044.pdf) by Amorós, Burger, Corlette, Kotschick, and Toledo.