# Is $U(n)$ a Kahler manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, differential-topology, manifolds

I am wondering if it is known whether the unitary group $U(n)$ is a Kahler manifold, and, if so, what is a reference for this.

Comment: $U(n)$ is not a complex manifold (it is defined by smooth non-holomorphic functions). More rigourously, if it were a complex manifold, then all its coordinate projections $M=(m_{ij})\mapsto m_{ij}$  would be constant by the maximum principle since $U(n)$ is compact.

Comment: For $n$ odd $U(n)$ is odd-dimensional as real manifold. By the way "is a Kähler manifold" is a quite vague question: for some given metric? diffeomorphic to a Kähler manifold? some left-invariance condition?

Comment: @Henri: $U(2)$ admits a complex structure (it is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$).

Comment: One could interpret the question as asking whether there is a Kähler manifold diffeomorphic to $U(n)$ for any $n$. The answer is no as $\pi_1(U(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ but as is discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/269966/21564), $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a Kähler group.

Comment: $U(n)$ does not admit a symplectic structure because $H^2(U(n)) = 0$.